# Metabase date calculation

Tags: mongodb, metabase

I would like Metabase to use a "greater than current date minus 30 days", but so far I haven't managed to make that work in a custom query with mongo.

How can I get this to work with Metabase?

```
{
    "$match": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "transactions.transactionTime": {
            "$gte": ISODate("Current Date - 30 days")
          }
        },
        {
          "transactions": null
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

Comment: Have you used moment library to perform such operation?

Comment: This is through the metabase query builder, no coding can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) to solve this:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$gte": [
        "$yourDateField",
        { "$subtract": [ISODate(), { "$multiply": [3600000, 24, 30] }] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I have also used `$multiply` with 3 parameters to show how computation works:

```
1) 3600000 millis = 1 hour
2) 24 hours = 1 day
3) 30 days
```

But you can write a shorter version:

```
{
  "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$gte": [
        "$yourDateField",
        { "$subtract": [ISODate(), 2592000000] }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can pass this to your query.

```js
const d = new Date();
const howManyDaysBefore = 30;
const thirtyDaysAgo = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() - howManyDaysBefore)).toISOString();

console.log(thirtyDaysAgo)
```

Comment: No variables can be used in the metabase query builder as far as I know.